Passwordless Authentication for Ansible
I have installed ansible and created new users for controller and remote hosts. Have set up the below steps, but getting error, can anyone suggest ??

Entered user using visudo, for both controller and client.

kt-ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Changed permit root login to yes and password auth to yes in sshd_config on remote host & restart sshd service.

Getting an error like below while copying the pub keys to remote host.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
Any other change required on sshd_config file ? Additionally I tried to setup permitrootlogin to yes and pubkeyauthentication to yes as well.
Many Thanks,
Piyush

please provide the output of ansible-playbook [your-cli parameters] -vvvv So we can see the users and details that you configured on your machine.

I do not have any playbook defined, so what you can suggest ?

Then the description of your problem is not clear. Please write it again with more details.

To get started with pubkeyauthentication you'll need passwordauthentication yes until you can login with keys.
Ensure to use ssh-copy-id to install you public key.
Note: Setting permitrootlogin yes goes against the use of sudo.
